# Force focus to a button element that was disabled in the previous render

Tags: reactjs, disabled-control

I have a button which opens a modal on the onClick event. I want the button to become disabled after the user clicks it, and enabled back when the modal closes.

I have set the initial state of **btnDisabled** as false and done this: (works as expected)

```
<Button
    label='Mybutton'
    className={['btn-outline-primary']}
    onClick={this.loadModel}
    disabled={this.state.btnDisabled}
/>
```

The onClick handler of the button is as follows:

```
loadModel(event) {
    this.setState({
      ModelOpen: true,
      btnDisabled: true,
    });
    this.activeElement = event.target;
  }
```

The modal **close button(x)** handler is this:

```
closeModel() {
    this.setState({
      ModelOpen: false,
      btnDisabled: false,
    });
    this.activeElement.focus();
  }
```

The problem is that the focus is not shifting to **Mybutton**. When I try to output **document.activeElement.outerHTML** on console log, it outputs the close button. Because of this, my tests are failing, as they are expecting MyButton to be the active element.

**UPDATE**
The tests work fine if I remove the button disabling logic. Here is the assertion that fails:

```
expect(wrapper.find('.btn-outline-primary').html()).toEqual(document.activeElement.outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding **eventListener** to Button element.
In javascript cause of event bubbling the target may vary.

try using `event.currentTarget` to get the button instance.
Hope this helps. It will be better if you provide a snippet of issue here.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect the code that is failing